# Cant Post data form android to php api

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have created an API using PHP and MYSQL and now i want to get data in Android.

My API works fine if i pass static data to it and run in browser but when i try to post data to android it throws an exception. I want to post username password for mysql database and a word through which it will return the word and definition in JSON format. Again as a I mentioned it works fine when i add static data in my php script but not working when posting through android. Here's what i've done so far

```
PHP
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$username=urlencode($_POST["username"]);
$pass=urlencode($_POST["pass"]);
$connect = mysqli_connect('pakscrabble.ipowermysql.com', $username, $pass,'csw19');

if (!$connect) { 

die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());


 }

$w=urlencode($_POST["wordtosearch"]);



$q="select * from words where word='".$w."' ";


$query=mysqli_query($connect,$q); 

$dict_data = array();

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
{ $dict_data[] = array( 
'word' => $row[0], 
'def' => $row[1] ); 
}


echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_encode($dict_data));
echo "</pre>";

?>

Android


        String urlString = params[0]; // URL to call
        String username = params[1];
        String pass=params[2];
        String wordtosearch=params[3];

        OutputStream out = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());

            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8")
                    + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");

            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("pass", "UTF-8") + "="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(pass, "UTF-8");

            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("wordtosearch", "UTF-8")
                    + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(wordtosearch, "UTF-8");

            writer.write(data);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            out.close();

            urlConnection.connect();
            JSONObject responseJSON = new JSONObject();
            Toast.makeText(c, String.valueOf(responseJSON.getString("def")), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String loginMessage = responseJSON.getString("loginMessage");
            String userName = responseJSON.getString("user");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(c, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return  "something happened";
        }
        return "Hello World!";
```

Never reaches the Hello World part and throws an exception

Comment: Please include the exception and stack trace in the question, without it we can't really say anything.

Comment: It shows no data for word

Comment: So you have an error you don't let us know and you expect help?
Catch it and log it to a file or upload the error message via an api.
You can't expect us to know not only the answer but the question too.